# Disable filter in the hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-filters

I have created a filter to apply for session of a particular bean. I enable the filter each time the session is fetched:

```
@Override
protected final Session getHibernateSession() {
   enableFilter("filterName",
         "parameterName", "parameterValue");
   return super.getHibernateSession();
}
```

Now I want that for a particular query, this filter need not be enabled. There exists an option to disable the filter, but I am not able to find the right place to do so. I tried:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = criteria();
// some restrictions and projections
disableFilter("filterName")
return find(criteria);
```

The problem is, when the find(criteria) is fired, the hibernate session is fetched again, which enables the filter.

Comment: I don't get it.  Just call disableFilter on the session and use that session to createCriteria and execute the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have created separate methods for enabling and disabling filters.

You will have to disable the filters in find(criteria) method itself.
Instead of doing :

```
getHibernateSession().createQuery(somequery);
```

You will have to do something like this :

```
Session session = getHibernateSession();
session.disableFilter("filterName");
session.createQuery(somequery);
```

This should work. I also found a link which can help:
https://www.tikalk.com/posts/2013/01/28/how-to-activate-and-deactivate-hibernate-filters/

Comment: Old link is dead, found a new one. https://www.tikalk.com/posts/2013/01/28/how-to-activate-and-deactivate-hibernate-filters/

Comment: Thanks. Updated the link in answer.